# How do you show value as a title in easyadmin bundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

in config.yml

```
edit:
                title:  'editing %firstname% '
                fields:
                    - {property: firstname, type: string}
                    - {property: lastname, type: string}
                    - {property: email, type: string}
                    - {property: password,type: password}
                    - {property: mobilenumber, type: string}
                    - enabled
```

i want the username to come up dynamically and %firstname% doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only display entity ID in edit view like this:

```
title: 'editing %%entity_id%%'
```

Starting from there, you can use Doctrine composite primary key to include firstname (or username?) in your primary key on User class:

```
/** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="string") */
private $username;
```

Comment: i'm aware of that and it doesn't help me cause i don't want to set a name as an id in my class.